# Отличия функций SendMessage и PostMessage

Tags: winapi

Чем отличаются функции `SendMessage` и `PostMessage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PostMessage** - Ставит сообщение в очередь, и код выполняется дальше.

**SendMessage** - Функция SendMessage шлет сообщение сразу

Answer (score 11):

*(Уточнение-комментарий к ответу [@Asen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5040/asen))*

- И `PostMessage`, и `SendMessage`, если пользоваться вашей терминологией, *"шлют сообщение сразу",* поскольку единственное, куда можно отослать сообщения (за исключением [**Nonqueued messages**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#nonqueued_messages)) - это в некоторую *внутреннюю очередь*.
- Это реализовано так, поскольку в противном случае решение `race conditions` типа *"50 потоков одновременно послали сделали `SendMessage`"* стало бы очень проблематичным.
- **Самое главное,** что нужно было написать про эти функции - это то, что [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) дожидается обработки сообщения и **возвращает результат,** а [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) просто кладет сообщение в очередь и совершенно не заботится о том, что произойдет дальше.
- Последний факт, кстати говоря, заметен из их сигнатур:

  ```
  BOOL WINAPI PostMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

  LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

SendMessage - синхронная, PostMessage - асинхронная.