# Имитация ввода с клавиатуры в другом приложении

Tags: c#

Нужно чтоб в другую программу имитировался ввод с клавиатуры, на оф сайте написано как это можно [сделать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code), но почемуто так не работает.
В Spy++ показывает это:
[image: Окно Spy++]

Пишу вот так:

```
IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow", "Калькулятор");

// Verify that Calculator is a running process.
if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
    return;
}

// Make Calculator the foreground application and send it 
// a set of calculations.
SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
SendKeys.SendWait("111");
```

но выдает ошибку что калькулятор не найден, подскажите что я делаю не так.

Windows 10 Pro 1909 x64
Spy++ 16.00.29428 (выпуск x86)
Калькулятор 10.1910.0.0 x64

Comment: Странно, вроде нормальный вопрос, воспроизводимый. А никто не отвечает. Добавьте информацию о версии ОС

Comment: @4per вы имеете в виду информации о версиях приложений и ОC?

Comment: У меня операционная система Windows 7, а у вас?

Comment: У меня класс у окна калькулятора `CalcFrame`

Comment: @4per или 8-ка или 10-ка у ТС'а

Comment: А разрядность приложения совпадает с разрядностью приложения, которое используется для поиска? А то, например, в AutoIt(Скриптовый язык для этих целей) есть 2 версии под х64 и х86, что как мне кажется может быть не с проста. Может быть еще проблема в том, что вы можете использовать программу для поиска х86, а ОС ваша х64.

Comment: @4per добавил то что нужно?

Comment: @NeulovimFox, Вроде, да. А х64 Spy++  вы не можете попробовать, как пишет iluxa1810 ? А ещё обратите внимание на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075131/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8?noredirect=1#comment1848124_1076096

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# - Симуляция ввода текста пользователем в консольное приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909307/c-%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: @Andrew не совсем, там вопрос про консольное приложение с имитацией ввода которой проблем нет, а калькулятор системное приложение, и там все работает по другому принципу. Вопрос в том, как к таким приложениям обращаться на примере калькулятора/

Comment: @UndefFox А ты пробовал тот код применить на калькуляторе? Нет? Нет никакой разницы. Посылай в калькулятор нажатия цифр и спецсимволов. Если что - консоль это тоже системное приложение. По-другому принципу работают разве что программы с веб-интерфейсом и видеоигры. А разницы между консольным приложением или блокнотом и калькулятором(работающим по горячим клавишам в т.ч.) особой нет. Это дубликат.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то давно, в древние времена, я для этого использовал функции WinAPI [SendMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) и [PostMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea) ([отличия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/106097/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-sendmessage-%D0%B8-postmessage)). 
Они позволяют отправить окну любое сообщение, в т.ч. и нажатия клавиш.

Возможно для реализации под .NET есть какие-то ограничения, связанные с работой фреймворка.

Comment: PostMessage не является надежным способом для имитации клавиатурного ввода: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513 SendKeys в C# использует Journal Hooks, которые работают чуть лучше, но ненамного. Поддерживаемый способ имитации клавиатурного в ввода в .NET - это [UI Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview), но и он конечно не позволяет надежно имитировать ввод в **любое** приложения, потому что эта задача просто неразрешима (если не входить в область написания собственных драйверов клавиатуры).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Ну у ТС (пока) проблема не с отправить, а взять дескриптор окна

Comment: @4per а в разрядности проблема не может быть? Ведь Intptr'ы, вроде, от разрядности к разрядности разные => если приложения поиска одной разрядности, а ОС другой, то не может невалидный дескриптор возвращаться и все такое?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри вот здесь:

https://github.com/kurumpa/dotSwitcher - это аналог пунто на c#

https://habr.com/ru/post/482644/ - реализация кейлоггера

Comment: ответы ссылками для даного ресурса -- плохая практика. Необходимо изменить ответ так что бы здесь был код в ответе или же конвертировать ответ в комментарий